# Cannot append specific columns of data from excel to a table without getting index errors

Tags: python

Im trying to get data from an excel file to a list by appending the list with a for loop. I set the range as (0, data.shape[0]) to include the full data set but that results in "string index out of range". I tried to change it to data.shape[1] and that results in "ValueError: Length of values (14) does not match length of index (1000)". When changing it to data.shape[2] I get, "tuple index out of range". I tried to change the range to (0, 1000) as that is the length of the excel file but that results in "string index out of range" as well.

[Here is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swgrb.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide sample data and your code typed in this post. Also, please provide an expected output. Thank you.

Comment: Please share your code and stacktrace as plain text and/or make sure your image renders properly

Answer (score 0):

Few things. Just to fix the very specific problem you are having change `str(data['some_col'])[i]` to `str(data['some_col'][i])`. You are not taking i-th element, you are first converting to string and then trying to take i-th character.

But the bigger point is that what you want to achieve can be achieved in more idiomatic way. In general you almost never should iterate over rows and definitely never with a for loop. What you want to do can even be done without iteration with something like this

```
df2['NewColumn'] = df2['Title'] + ' ' + df2['Certificate']
```

or if you want to have something closer to iterative approach use `apply`:

```
df2['SomeCol'] = df2 \
    .fillna('na') \
    .apply(
        lambda row: ' '.join([
            row['Certificate'],
            row['Title']
        ]),
        axis=1
     )
```